# Approximation with Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Maclaurin expansion for $f(x) = \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}$. Taking $x = 1/3$ how many terms do we need to approximate the value of $\log 2$ with $6$ exact decimal places?

I've tried to do the Maclaurin expansion, taking into account $\log$ is the same as $\ln$, but in the second derivate I have an indetermination $0/n$ and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: Subtract the Maclaurin series of $\log(1-x)$ from that of $\log(1+x)$ (since $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)=\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$).

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$
f(x) = \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}  = \sum_{n = 0}^{t}\frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} 
+ \sum_{k = t+1}^{\infty}\frac{2x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} 
< \sum_{n = 1}^{t}\frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2t+3}\sum_{k = t+1}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}
$$

$$
\log \frac{1+x}{1-x}  < \sum_{n = 1}^{t}\frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + \frac{2}{2t+3} \cdot\frac{x^{2t+3}}{1 - x^2}
$$

For $x = 1/3$, to get $f(1/3) = \log 2$ accurate to six decimal places, we need the minimum value of $t$ for which
$$
\frac{2}{2t+3} \cdot\frac{(1/3)^{2t+3}}{1 - (1/3)^2} < 10^{-6}
$$
The smallest value of $t$ for which this happens is $t = 5$. Hence we need a minimum of $5$ terms to get $\log 2$ accurate to six decimal places.

Comment: hod do you know log is equal to the sum ??

Comment: Is it the infinite derivate or somerthing?

Comment: @Clauuu You can use the standard series for $\log(1 \pm x)$ for $|x| < 1$. The even terms cancel out leaving only the odd terms